# LaTeX non-backslash symbol aliases

Tags: symbols

Reading the Comprehensive Latex Symbol List (30 November 2015), I find on page 29 that `*` corresponds to `\ast` - at least as a glyph. Which are the other non-backslash (mathematical) symbols which correspond to a backslash symbol name in Latex, and what do they correspond to? For example, I would expect +, - and / to have corresponding backslash-names.

Comment: the don't by default, you can of course define command names if you wish.

Comment: So for example +, -, and / are their own symbols, not aliases? What would be a comprehensive list of all such non-backslash symbols?

Comment: `*` and `\ast` are not really aliases either, they are defined separately but with the same definition, one is not defined in terms of the other. _every_ character in math mode is such a symbol so for example `a` is defined to come from the math italic font but `1` is defined to come from the upright roman font.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The complete list should be

```
* \ast
[ \lbrack
] \rbrack
| \vert
= \Relbar
```

and you can maybe add

```
\{ \lbrace
\} \rbrace
   \backslash
```

Note that `\mid` produces the same symbol as `|` or `\vert`, but with the type “relation”; similarly `\colon` produces a colon, but with a different spacing from `:`.

There is also `\slash`, that produces `/` but with a line break allowed after it.

I'm not sure why `\ast` has been defined in plain TeX (possibly because Knuth sometimes needed `*` with a different meaning). The reason for `\lbrack` is for providing `[` in a context where the latter cannot be used because it could be mistaken for the start of an optional argument; `\rbrack` is there for symmetry. For sure, Knuth needed `|` for his own purposes, so he provided `\vert` as an alias.

With `amsmath` the same symbol as `|` is produced by `\lvert` and `\rvert`, but with the types “opening” and “closing” respectively.

The reason for `\Relbar` is because the equals sign is used as extender for long double arrows; in some fonts a different symbol might be used, so `\Relbar` is by default defined as `=`, but can be redefined without the need to modify the definitions for `\Longrightarrow` and `\Longleftarrow` needn't be.

`\lbrace` and `\rbrace` are useful in order to fool smart editors that like to pair delimiters.

There is no alias for `+` and `-`, but they can be easily defined.

A reversed situation happens for `<` and `\langle` (and similarly for `>` and `\rangle`): the constructions `\bigl<` or `\left<` are shorthands for `\bigl\langle` and `\left\langle`, but `<` should *never* be used alone for denoting an angle bracket.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle They're reversed: `\left<` is a synonym for `\left\langle`, but the symbol produced is not `<`.